# Recent alternative rock song with gambling theme

Tags: identify-this-song, alternative-rock

I'm trying to find a song I heard on alternative radio about two years ago.  It was poppy alternative rock, and the singer had a distinctive voice that reminded me of [Lightspeed Champion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yQYQpXq1Uko) (Devonte Hynes) --perhaps with a similar British accent.

The lyrics had a number of stock phrases based on gambling --i.e. "roll the dice", "cut the cards", etc.  I think it was a love song.

Answer (score 2):

Was it "[Don't Sit Down 'Cause I've Moved Your Chair](https://youtu.be/39p3Oub5k7M)" by the Arctic Monkeys?  It came out in 2011 and includes the phrase "roll the dice."

Comment: Thanks!  That's a good suggestion, but this song has much more of a hard rock feel than the one I remember.

Comment: Oh, ok I'll keep thinking/looking then. Because there's a few floating around in my head that might fit the bill.